# How to hide and view ModalPopupExtender?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am using 4 Modalpopupextender in my start-up page of my project. When I run my start-up page, the panels which I have set under PopupControlID in Modalpopupextender are visible even before the specified TargetControlID is clicked. I have tried to set visible of those to false but it dint helped me and I also tried to create a css class to hide a panel when page is loaded and to view the panel when specified button is clicked but it neither helped me. Please help. Thank you.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<style type = "text/css">
        .hidePanel 
        {
            display:none;
        }
        .showpanel
        {
            display : block;
        }
    .panel
    {
        background : gray;
        padding : 10px;
    }
    div ul ul 
    {
        display: none;
    }
    div ul li:hover > ul 
    {
        display: block;
    }
    div ul li ul:hover > ul 
    {
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:modalpopupextender ID="Modalpopupextender1" CancelControlID = "Button8" TargetControlID = "Button2" PopupControlID = "StaffSP" runat="server"></asp:modalpopupextender>
    <asp:modalpopupextender ID="Modalpopupextender2" CancelControlID = "Button10" TargetControlID = "Button3" PopupControlID = "StaffFP" runat="server"></asp:modalpopupextender>
    <asp:modalpopupextender ID="Modalpopupextender3" CancelControlID = "Button12" TargetControlID = "Button5" PopupControlID = "AdminSP" runat="server"></asp:modalpopupextender>
    <asp:modalpopupextender ID="Modalpopupextender4" CancelControlID = "Button14" TargetControlID = "Button6" PopupControlID = "AdminSP" runat="server"></asp:modalpopupextender>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="XX-Large" Text="Automated Examination System"></asp:Label><br /> <br /><br /> 
    <asp:Panel ID = "Main" runat = "server" Height="181px" Width="275px">                                                                                                                         
    <ul>
    <li style="margin-removed 33px; width: 169px;"> <asp:LinkButton ID = "LinkAdmin" runat = "server" onclick="LinkAdmin_Click">Coordinator</asp:LinkButton></li>
    <li style="width: 172px; margin-removed 33px"> <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkStaff" runat="server" onclick="LinkStaff_Click">Staff</asp:LinkButton></li>
    <li style="margin-removed 33px"> <asp:LinkButton ID = "LinkStudent" runat = "server">Student</asp:LinkButton>
            <ul>
            <li><asp:LinkButton ID = "LinkButton1" runat = "server">Fresh Registration</asp:LinkButton></li>
            <li><asp:LinkButton ID = "LinkButton2" runat = "server">Re Registration</asp:LinkButton></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    <asp:Panel ID="StaffLogin" runat="server" Height="59px" 
        style="z-index: 1; left: 302px; top: 112px; position: absolute; height: 59px; width: 275px" 
        Visible="False" Width="275px">
        Staff<br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Login" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="New Staff" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Fogot Password" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="AdminLogin" runat="server" 
        style="z-index: 1; left: 302px; top: 193px; position: absolute; height: 78px; width: 275px" 
        Visible="False" Width="275px">
        Admin<br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Login" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="New Admin" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" Text="Forgot Password" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="StaffSP" runat="server" Height="48px" Width="274px">
        Staff SP<br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button8" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="StaffFP" runat="server" Height="48px" Width="274px">
        Staff FP<br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button9" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button10" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
        <br />
        <br />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="AdminSP" runat="server" Height="48px" Width="274px">
        Admin SP<br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button11" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button12" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
        <br />
        <br />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="AdminFP" runat="server" Height="48px" Width="274px">
        AdminFP<br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button13" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button14" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />

    </asp:Panel>

    </form>
</body>
</html>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class TrailPopup : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void LinkAdmin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AdminLogin.Visible = true;
        StaffLogin.Visible = false;
    }
    protected void LinkStaff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AdminLogin.Visible = false;
        StaffLogin.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

EDIT :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<style type = "text/css">
        .hidePanel 
        {
            display:none;
        }
        .showpanel
        {
            display : block;
        }
    .panel
    {
        background : gray;
        padding : 10px;
    }
    div ul ul 
    {
        display: none;
    }
    div ul li:hover > ul 
    {
        display: block;
    }
    div ul li ul:hover > ul 
    {
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="XX-Large" Text="Automated Examination System"></asp:Label><br />&nbsp;<br /><br />&nbsp;
    <asp:Panel ID = "Main" runat = "server" Height="181px" Width="275px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <ul>
    <li style="margin-left: 33px; width: 169px;">&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID = "LinkAdmin" runat = "server" onclick="LinkAdmin_Click">Coordinator</asp:LinkButton></li>
    <li style="width: 172px; margin-left: 33px">&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkStaff" runat="server" onclick="LinkStaff_Click">Staff</asp:LinkButton></li>
    <li style="margin-left: 33px">&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID = "LinkStudent" runat = "server">Student</asp:LinkButton>
            <ul>
            <li><asp:LinkButton ID = "LinkButton1" runat = "server">Fresh Registration</asp:LinkButton></li>
            <li><asp:LinkButton ID = "LinkButton2" runat = "server">Re Registration</asp:LinkButton></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    <asp:Panel ID="StaffLogin" runat="server" Height="59px" 
        style="z-index: 1; left: 302px; top: 112px; position: absolute; height: 59px; width: 275px" 
        Visible="False" Width="275px">
        Staff<br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Login" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="New Staff" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Fogot Password" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="AdminLogin" runat="server" style="left: 302px; top: 193px; position: absolute; height: 78px; width: 275px" Visible="False" Width="275px">Admin<br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Login" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="New Admin" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" Text="Forgot Password" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="StaffSP" Visible = "false" runat="server" Height="48px" Width="274px">
        Staff SP<br />
        <asp:modalpopupextender ID="Modalpopupextender1" CancelControlID = "Button8" TargetControlID = "Button2" PopupControlID = "StaffSP" runat="server"></asp:modalpopupextender>
        <asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button8" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="StaffFP" Visible = "false" runat="server" Height="48px" Width="274px">
        Staff FP<br />
        <asp:modalpopupextender ID="Modalpopupextender2" CancelControlID = "Button10" TargetControlID = "Button3" PopupControlID = "StaffFP" runat="server"></asp:modalpopupextender>
        <asp:Button ID="Button9" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button10" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
        <br />
        <br />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="AdminSP" Visible = "false" runat="server" Height="48px" Width="274px">
        Admin SP<br />
        <asp:modalpopupextender ID="Modalpopupextender4" CancelControlID = "Button14" TargetControlID = "Button6" PopupControlID = "AdminSP" runat="server"></asp:modalpopupextender>
        <asp:Button ID="Button11" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button12" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
        <br />
        <br />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="AdminFP" Visible = "false" runat="server" Height="48px" Width="274px">
        AdminFP<br />
        <asp:modalpopupextender ID="Modalpopupextender3" CancelControlID = "Button12" TargetControlID = "Button5" PopupControlID = "AdminFP" runat="server"></asp:modalpopupextender>
        <asp:Button ID="Button13" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button14" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />

    </asp:Panel>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: provide your aspx code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your css class hide panel in every PopupControl used for modalpopupextender control:

```
  `<asp:Panel ID="StaffSP" runat="server" CssClass="hide" Height="48px" Width="274px" >
    Staff SP<br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button8" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="StaffFP" runat="server" Height="48px" Width="274px" style="display:none;">
    Staff FP<br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button9" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button10" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
    <br />
    <br />
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="AdminSP" runat="server" Height="48px" Width="274px" CssClass="hidePanel">
    Admin SP<br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button11" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button12" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
    <br />
    <br />
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="AdminFP" runat="server" Height="48px" Width="274px" Visible="false">
    AdminFP<br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button13" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button14" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />

</asp:Panel>`
```

Comment: Rojalin, I have done this already. But this hides the panel when I run my startup page but it does not trigger when the specified button is clicked.

Comment: Specified button (link buttons) ?? I run the code on my system and it Give the result as I click the link buttons

Comment: No, specified button are not the link buttons. Those link button are just to categorize for staff login and coordinator login. When you click staff link button a panel will be visible where you can find 3 buttons namely Login,NewStaff and Forgot Password (not link buttons). When you click on newstaff or forgot password from the panel visble, it has to popup respective panel specified under popcontrolid in modalpopupextender.

Comment: Plese  use style as display:none instead of visible in your panel control , then your problem will be solved. check this one:
`<asp:Panel ID="StaffSP" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Height="48px" Width="274px" style="display:none;">
        Staff SP<br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button8" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
    </asp:Panel>`

Answer (score 1):

you have put all the 4 TargetControlIDs inside the panels which are not visible

Comment: Even that dint helped me :(. I have posted the code as you suggested in EDIT part. Please have a look at it.

Comment: tried ur code with few changes ,, it worked at my side

Comment: add CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none" to all PopupControls , add BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"  to all ModalPopupExtender and following is the css  .modalBackground
        {
            background-color: Black;
            filter: alpha(opacity=90);
            opacity: 0.8;
        }
        .modalPopup
        {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            border-width: 3px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: black;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 140px;}

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. You solved my problem. Thank you once again :)